# ¿Cómo mostrar una imagen en Qt5 y Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7, pyqt5

Estoy tratando de mostrar una imagen en una interfaz grafica que diseñe en Qt5 y que esta programada en python, estoy tratando de mostrar una imagen en la figura self.axes5 pero se cierra la interfaz cuando quiero mostrar dicha imagen.

```
self.figure5 = Figure()
self.canvas5 = FigureCanvasQTAgg(self.figure5)
self.axes5 = self.figure5.add_subplot(111)
self.plot_layout5 = QVBoxLayout()
self.plot_layout5.addWidget(self.canvas5)
self.widget_5.setLayout(self.plot_layout5)

self.axes5.clear()
img = mpimg.imread('Cabeza-360.png')
self.axes5.plot(img)
self.canvas5.draw()
```

Gracias por la ayuda

Answer (score 0):

Imagino que puedes entender este código:

```
# Importar todo lo necesario
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *

# Crear una ventana
app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
ventana = QtWidgets.QWidget()
ventana.setWindowTitle("PyQt5 - Pixmap")
ventana.show()

# Crear la imagen
contenedor = QLabel(ventana) # Crear un Label
imagen = QPixmap("imagen.jpg") # Crear un objeto QPixmap, que es una imagen
contenedor.setPixmap(imagen) # Establecer el contenido del Label como un Pixmap que contiene la imagen especificada

# Ejecutar la aplicación
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```